# Android app with multiple windows

Tags: android

I am writing a android app with multiple windows (screens).
While reading tutorials I see them suggesting to use one Activity per screen.

It there a alternative where i can use only one Activity but different layouts (xml files)?

Do I have to use one Activity (one xml per activity) when creating a android app : is that the standard practice used by android app developers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can either make a activity for very screen or can create one Activity and different fragments

Comment: Its just that maintaining code will be a lot easier with multiple activity classes. If you are planning to put all eggs in one basket you can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing application with multiple windows means try to use Action bar and fragments since the tab activities are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same component names on each xml you can use multiple xml for the same Activity

Just call

```
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);
```

Just ensure that the component names are all these like EditText etc are all there or calls like below will fail.

```
    ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Is there a reason you want to reuse layouts with the same main code?